# apt-key list doesn't show key IDs

Tags: debian, apt, stretch

On Debian Stretch (testing) last `aptitude update` noticed that I have expired keys, so I've decided to remove them, but running `apt-key list` doesn't show key IDs and `apt-key update` is deprecated and does nothig, how can I get the ID of expired key then?

```
# apt-key list   
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2013-10-10 [SC] [expired: 2016-10-01]
uid           [ expired] I2P Debian Package Repository         <killyourtv@i2pmail.org>

pub   rsa4096 2013-04-06 [SC] [expired: 2016-04-10]
uid           [ expired] KillYourTV Debian repository signing key <killyourtv@mail.i2p>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [`debian-archive-keyring`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/debian-archive-keyring):

> The Debian project digitally signs its Release files. This package contains the archive keys used for that.

```
sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```